# Difference between setting control Parent property and using Controls.Add()?

Tags: c#, user-controls

more specifically, are these statements

```
ownerControl.GroupBox1.Controls.Remove(childControl);
ownerControl.Controls.Add(childControl);
```

an equivalent to

```
childControl.Parent = ownerControl;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking in reflector, it looks like `Parent` just calls `Add` (when the new parent is non-null). The `Controls.Add` deals with taking it away from the old parent. So actually, the following are functionally equivalent (when `ownerControl` is not null):

```
ownerControl.Controls.Add(childControl); // note no Remove etc
```

and:

```
childControl.Parent = ownerControl;
```

Counter-intuitive, but a quick test shows that it works.